# How to get list of all tf frames programatically?

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-kinetic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a question on how to obtain tf frames in a ros node (preferrably Python).
I am aware of the method `tf2_ros.Buffer.lookup_transform()`, however, one has to specify source and target frame for that.

Lets say I have an array of known markers, but only a subset of them are detected by the camera. I want to know which of these markers are detected by looking at the existing tf frames. Is there a more elegant way to do so instead of looping over all possible markers and try to lookup the transform in a try catch block?

Thanks in advance!

P.S I am using kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

---

EDIT:
In the tutorial [TfUsingPython](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython) I found the method `allFramesAsString()` but it seems to use tf, not tf2. would there be an equivalence in tf2? Or is it generally a bad practice to mix the use of tf and tf2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347857/how-to-get-list-of-all-tf-frames-programatically?/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems #q261460 is at least a partial duplicate of your question.

> In the tutorial [TfUsingPython](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython) I found the method `allFramesAsString()` but it seems to use tf, not tf2. would there be an equivalence in tf2? Or is it generally a bad practice to mix the use of tf and tf2?

TF has been implemented on-top of TF2 for quite some time now, so you cannot really "mix" them: it would all be using TF2 in the end.

As to the method you found: there is `tf2::BufferCore::allFramesAsYAML(double current_time) const` in TF2 (and `allFramesAsStringNoLock()` is available as well).

The Python API of TF2 is essentially a mirror of the C++ API, so you should be able to call that from Python as well (I have not verified this).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on 2020-03-30**:
Since the Python API is rather poorly documented, here is sth if someone has the same problem as me: After some further research I found some example usage of the Python API here: [examples_tf2_py](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/tree/eloquent/examples_tf2_py). Probably this still does not contain all methods of the C++ API, but imo it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up searching alternative to native tf library functions to solve my problem.
The reason was that after getting `allFramesAsYAML()` (or in Python `tfBuffer_ros.all_frames_as_yaml()`) to work i found out that it will return *all* frames that have been in the tf buffer, regardless of whether the frame is in the current tf topic or not. The output was:

```
marker1: 
  parent: 'camera'
  broadcaster: '/marker_tracker'
  rate: 30.401
  most_recent_transform: 1585572193.003
  oldest_transform: 1585572190.503
  buffer_length: 2.500
marker2: 
  parent: 'camera'
  broadcaster: '/marker_tracker'
  rate: 30.457
  most_recent_transform: 1585572192.703
  oldest_transform: 1585572190.503
  buffer_length: 2.200
marker3: 
  parent: 'camera'
  broadcaster: '/marker_tracker'
  rate: 27.709
  most_recent_transform: 1585572195.538
  oldest_transform: 1585572191.568
  buffer_length: 3.970
```

I occluded marker2 after a while, and it still appeared in the output. The only difference is that "most_recent_transform" stopped updating.

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-30**:\

> The only difference is that "most_recent_transform" stopped updating.

doesn't that align with what you were trying to achieve? You wrote:

> I want to know which of these markers are detected by looking at the existing tf frames

Thing is: TF frames "don't exist", so seeing whether they "still exist" is not really something you can do.

Even TF itself (ie: the internals of the provided libraries) will look at `most_recent_transform` to determine whether a transform is still up-to-date and relevant.

In your case you could see how long ago the transform was updated and determine -- based on some threshold -- whether the last detected pose for a marker is "too old".

**Comment by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on 2020-03-30**:
You are right, by looking at the update time I can filter the tfs. I was just rather looking for sth. simpler (e.g. boolean) that shows if a certain tf frame is updated or not, i.e. "existing", but I was not aware that the internal libraries use the mechanics of update time. Thanks for clarifying that!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-30**:\

> I was just rather looking for sth. simpler (e.g. boolean) that shows if a certain tf frame is updated or not

well, think about it: what would it mean for a frame to "be updated or not"? How would TF determine this to set that boolean `true` or `false`?

Probably be comparing the time at which a frame was last updated to some sort of maximum allowable age .. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Building off the other answers, here's a snippet of runnable code that I wound up with:

```
import rospy
import tf2_ros
import time
import yaml

rospy.init_node('ipython')

tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(tf_buffer)
time.sleep(5.0)

frames_dict = yaml.safe_load(tf_buffer.all_frames_as_yaml())
frames_list = list(frames_dict.keys())
```

(Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, running noetic)

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2022-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-04**:
I tried porting your snippet into ROS2 but haven't had success so far. Spun off a new question [Python's all tf frames function in ROS2 only returns some frames](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24731) FYI.